# SQL Grouping by intervals, counting and summing

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I need to find the total sales for employees having work experience between 15-20 years, and greater than 20 years, in Microsoft server SQL/T-SQL.

I have a dataset that looks like that:

```
    Hiredate       EmployeeID     Sales
0   1986-01-02     90             20,000
1   1989-02-30     80             10,000  
2   2000-01-20     91             50,000
3   2009-05-07     92             60,000
4   2007-07-06     47             30,000
5   1999-01-24     66             44,000
6   2005-09-22     21             30,000
```

What I have done so far is:

```
   SELECT SUM(EmployeeID) 
   FROM (
   SELECT DATEDIFF(year,Hiredate, GETDATE()), COUNT(EmployeeID)
   FROM abc.table
   WHERE DATEDIFF(year, Hiredate, GETDATE()) > 20
   GROUP BY DATEDIFF(year,Hiredate, GETDATE())
   )
```

This portion gave me the difference in date, and the count of employees, but i'm stuck on how to seperate the groups and then sum the sales.

```
   SELECT DATEDIFF(year,Hiredate, GETDATE()), COUNT(EmployeeID)
   FROM abc.table
   WHERE DATEDIFF(year, Hiredate, GETDATE()) > 20
   GROUP BY DATEDIFF(year,Hiredate, GETDATE())
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `datediff()` -- it does not do what you expect.  It counts the number of "boundaries" between two dates.  With year, that is midnight between Dec 31 and Jan 1.

In addition, applying functions on columns generally makes it harder for the to create the best execution plan.

You seem to want:

```
SELECT SUM(SALES) 
FROM abc
WHERE HireDate >= DATEADD(year, -20, GETDATE()) AND
      HireDate < DATEADD(year, -14 GETDATE());
```

To get the values for two groups, one method is conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN HireDate >= DATEADD(year, -20, GETDATE()) AND
                     HireDate < DATEADD(year, -14 GETDATE())
                THEN SALES
           END),
        SUM(CASE WHEN HireDate < DATEADD(year, -20, GETDATE()) 
                 THEN SALES
           END)
FROM abc;
```

Another is to put the values in rows:

```
SELECT grp, SUM(sales)
FROM abc CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES (CASE WHEN HireDate < DATEADD(year, -20, GETDATE()) THEN '20+ YEARS'
                   WHEN HireDate < DATEADD(year, -14, GETDATE()) THEN '15-20 YEARS'
                   ELSE '< 15 YEARS'
              END)
     ) v(grp)
GROUP BY grp
ORDER BY MIN(HIREDATE);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select
    sum(case 
        when datediff(year, hiredate, getdate()) between 15 and 20 
        then sales 
        else 0 
    end) sales_15_20,
    sum(case 
        when datediff(year, hiredate, getdate()) > 20 
        then sales 
        else 0 
    end) sales_above_20
from mytable
```

This query will give you a unique record with two columns, with the sum of sales for each criteria.

Following up on Gordon Linoff's below recommendation, a more optimized way to phrase this is:

```
select
    sum(case 
        when hiredate 
            between dateadd(year, -20, getdate()) and dateadd(year, -15, getdate())
        then sales 
        else 0 
    end) sales_15_20,
    sum(case 
        when hiredate < dateadd(year, -20, getdate()) 
        then sales 
        else 0 
    end) sales_above_20
from mytable
```